# How to use a Data from JSON response into a variable in Swift

Tags: json, swift, api

I'm trying to use an object (web href - from response) from the JSON Response, that I later want to convert into a variable. But at the moment I'm only able to get the entire JSON response.

What I need is just one URL out of it.

**My Code**

```
import UIKit

import Foundation
#if canImport(FoundationNetworking)
import FoundationNetworking
#endif

var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore (value: 0)

let parameters = "{\n    \"customerInternalReference\":\"William's Swift Bootcamp\",\n    \"workflowDefinition\":{\n        \"key\": 10015\n    },\n    \"userReference\": \"Lets get swifty\",\n    \"tokenLifetime\": \"100m\"\n}"
let postData = parameters.data(using: .utf8)

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://urlhere.com")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("Basic masked for security", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = postData

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
  guard let data = data else {
    print(String(describing: error))
    semaphore.signal()
    return
  }
    
    
    do {
        
        
        let response = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
              
              print(response)
    }
    
    catch{
        print(error)
}
    
  semaphore.signal()
}


task.resume()
semaphore.wait()
```

**My Response (Displayed in Debug Area)**

```
{
    account =     {
        id = "accountidcomeshere";
    };
    sdk =     {
        token = "tokkencomeshere";
    };
    timestamp = "2022-09-13T21:35:07.347Z";
    web =     {
        href = "https:urlcomeshere.com/needThis/";
    };
    
}
```

Comment: The `response` object you get is likely a dictionary. Set a breakpoint at that line and inspect it to be sure. If you know how to use dictionaries, you should be able to easily extract the value you need. If you don't yet know how to use Swift dictionaries, I'd highly recommend reading about them first.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this approach to get to the `href` element of the response:

```
let response = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String : Any]
print("\n-----> response: \(response)")

if let web = (response["web"] as? [String : String]),
   let href = web["href"] {
    print("\n--> href: \(href)") // --> href: https:urlcomeshere.com/needThis/
}
```

Note, using `DispatchSemaphore` seems to be from the dark ages,
there are more modern ways to achieve an API call.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback , let me try this and get back to you. 

And I did not write the code , It was generated by Postman and I just used it.

Comment: did my answer worked for you?